# AngularJS Evaluate a Attribute directive after a Element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the following angular plugin
https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider

My goal is modify the "legends" generated by the  directive. For this, the directive receives an Array on the rz-slider-options attribute. Example:

In the Controller:

```
angular
    .module('exampleApp')
    .controller('MyController', Controller);

function Controller () {
    var $ctrl = this;
    $ctrl.slider = {
        value: 1,
        options: {
            showTicksValues: true,
            stepsArray:[{value: 1, legend: 'red'}, {value: 1, legend: 'green'}, {value: 1, legend: 'blue'}, {value: 1, legend: 'red'}]
        }
    }
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as $ctrl">
      <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.value" rz-slider-options="slider.options" ></rzslider>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be generate the following:
[image]

My idea it's add a custom directive to modify some DOM elements related to this directive. Suppose that my directive it's called `my-directive`, I want to do something like this:

```
angular
    .module('exampleApp')
    .directive('reds', MenuGeo);

MenuGeo.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function MenuGeo($timeout){
    var ddo = {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFn
    };
    return ddo;

    function linkFn(scope, el, attrs){
        var legendsList = el[0].getElementsByClassName('rz-tick-legend');
        console.log(legendsList);
    }
}
```

Then, I am modified the HTML like this:

```
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyController as $ctrl">
          <rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.value" rz-slider-options="slider.options" reds></rzslider>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But the `console.log` of my directive returns `[]`. Therefore I think that the element directive `rzslider` it is continue working when my directive has been called.

My question is: **How achieve that my directive will be evaluate after that the entire work of the rzslider has been done?**

A codepen it's available in here: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/mRBdBy

**UPDATE**

I've been achieve that my directive get the elements, but I need to add a `$timeout` sentence for achieve this. My new questions are:

**Why my directive were not evaluated after the directive rzslider and how i could achieve this without use $timeout?**

Answer (score 0):

What you seek is the default behavior, you should be able to access the html markup of the `rzslider`  directive using jQuery's **[element.children() function](https://api.jquery.com/children/)** (to get direct descendents) or the **[element.find() function](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** (to find any descendents) from within the directive's linker function. Something like this and then do what you want with the elements.

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){

      // Set all direct descendent's background colours to black
      element.children().css("background", "black");

      // Set all direct descendent's text colours to white
      element.children().css("color", "white");

      // Give the slider node a red border
      $(".rzslider .rz-pointer").css("border", "3px solid red");

      // etc
  };
});
```

Sample usage:

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="150" my-directive></rzslider>
```

Comment: I've seen your updated question along with your codepen example. The problem appears to be the `el[0]` part which evaluates immediately (and before the DOM has loaded). Functions such as `el.children()` and `el.find()` on the other hand execute once their DOM nodes have loaded and so can be used in place of `el[0]` in your example.

Comment: I think you can use `el[0]` but only after the DOM has loaded, and to ensure this it must be wrapped within a `$timeout` function or alternatively you can use JQuery's `$(document).ready(function() { .. }` function for similar effect.